# Programmatically add item to sharepoint list from window application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, client-object-model, windows-authentication, adfs

How to add item to SharePoint list from window application using claim based authentication ?
it gives 401 forbidden error. user is authenticated from ADFS server.

Answer (score 2):

how about following msdn? try using `ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext` instead

```
string targetSite = "http://SharePointServer/";
using (ClientContext CNX = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(targetSite))
{
            //Load Libraries from SharePoint
            CNX.Load(CNX.Web.Lists);
            CNX.ExecuteQuery();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(CNX, "/" + "Shared Documents" + "/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName.ToString()), fs, true);
            }
        }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx

if it doesnt work and still returns a 403 than it has to be an issue with ADFS not setup properly! check and refer to this:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/06/04/using-the-client-object-model-with-a-claims-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

**EDIT**

after some digging about i did find this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295953/claim-auth-from-adfs

they have a similar issue to you and required authentication from adfs! the issue is its complex and so he made a quick bolg on his findings:

http://jwillmer.de/blog/2013/01/04/sharepoint-online-with-adfs-authentication/

his solution :

https://github.com/jwillmer/SharePointAuthentication

Comment: its asking for username and password.. not authenticate window user

Comment: ammended the answer

Comment: please dont just add alot of external links! Those links tend to move/die/get lost. Instead please add some examples from the external links, and *then* link to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your Build Configuration for your windows application is set to

> Platform Target: (Any CPU)

or

> Platform Target (x64)

in Project Properties --> Build --> General in Visual studio

For setting permissions on ClientContext:

```
CNX.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

or

```
CNX.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Also, have you seen [this blogpost](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/shailensukul/archive/2010/09/14/adfs-2-0-and-sharepoint-client-om.aspx)? It has some helper dll that seems to be helpful

Comment: its giving error because of adfs authentication. i cant get authenticated client context

Comment: Why do you need the client context to add an item to a list?

Comment: because i m adding item from window application and context is authenticated from adfs

Comment: Can you please post some of your code so we can get an idea of your approach

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: please dont use comments as "chat". It clutters up the site with irrellevant info. We have a chat forum for just this purpose:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/411/sharepoint